# Android, WebRTC 360 video player

Tags: android, webrtc, surfaceview, 360-virtual-reality

I want to display 360 degree video through webrtc in Android. Since an URI is not available for webrtc video streams, common players such as libvlc or exoplayer cannot be used. Only option i found is to add 360 video capability to webrtc's existing renderer. Is this the correct and only possible way to do this? If yes please guide me to implement the same.

Comment: Have you found any solution for it

Comment: Not found any native solution. As an alternative you can try using web solutions. We tried with video.js 360 player in webview. It's working fine. But performance issues will be there  for high resolution videos.